# Sending email in grails from a java class

Tags: java, grails, groovy, closures

I have a grails app with [MailService](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/mail) plugin. I need to send an email from a java class using `sendMail(Closure callable)` method.

From a groovy class I do it the next way:

```
mailService.sendMail
{
   to ["test@gmail.com"]
   subject "Mail Subject"
   body "this is a message body")
}
```

How can I do the same from a java class?

Comment: The [JavaMail API](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: You could call a groovy service?

Comment: You can inject MailService into the java class using resources.groovy. Then use MailService from java class itself.

Answer (score 0):

At first inject `mailService` into your java class. Let's assume your java class name is `JavaMailSender` then the code for that class can look like following

```
    class JavaMailSender {

        @Autowired
        private MailService mailService;

        private void methodAsClosure(MailMessageBuilder builder) {
            builder.to(Arrays.asList("purno998@gmail.com"));
            builder.subject("Mail Subject");
            builder.body("this is a message body");
        }

        void sendMail() {
            MethodClosure closure = new MethodClosure(this, "methodAsClosure");
            mailService.sendMail(closure);
        }
     }
```

Now just one thing left that is you have to register this `JavaMailSender` as a bean in `grails-app/conf/resources.groovy` like this

```
    beans = {
        javaMailSender(JavaMailSender)
    }
```

Courtesy goes to http://www.jroller.com/melix/entry/coding_a_groovy_closure_in for the nice tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Ashraf, the mailService is available, but when I call `mailService.sendMail(closure);` MailMessageBuilder builder is null. What else I missed?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Are you sure that the `builder` is null not the `mailService`? If you use the `JavaMailSender` class by creating a new instance of it instead of injecting the bean then the `mailService` would be null. You can use it just like any `grails service` or `spring bean`.